# The connection between determinant of a complex matrix and determinant of a real matrix comes from it

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

Now suppose $Z\in M(n,\Bbb{C})$, and for each entry $Z_{jk}$, we write it as
$$
Z_{jk}=X_{jk}+iY_{jk}
$$
and replace it by the $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
X_{j, k} & -Y_{j, k} \\
Y_{j, k} & X_{j, k}
\end{array}\right)
$$
Thus we get a new real matrix denoted by $\Bbb{R}Z$, which lies in $M(2n,\Bbb{R})$. I want to prove
$$
\operatorname{det}\Bbb{R}Z=|\operatorname{det}Z|^2
$$
It's true clearly when $n=1$, but how about bigger $n$? I think it's still true, but I can't compute it. Maybe I need to consider induction on $n$?
Hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can show by elementary row and column operations that the determinant in question is equal to the determinant of
$$
\pmatrix{I&iI\\0&I}
\pmatrix{X&-Y\\Y&X}
\pmatrix{I&-iI\\0&I}
=
\pmatrix{X+iY&0\\Y&X-iY}
$$
The determinant is now the product of the determinants of the diagol blocks, and thus the claimed value follows.